# "Databases running in compatibility range, upgrade recommended" when NeedsUpgrade=False

Tags: 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, database, health-analyzer, warning

- SharePoint Health Analyzer warning: Databases running in compatibility range, upgrade recommended. 
  Explanation: The following databases have versions that are older than the current SharePoint software, but are within the backwards compatible range: DB_Content
- Ran `Upgrade-SPContentDatabase DB_Content` and it returned

> WARNING: Database [SPContentDatabase Name=DB_Content] does not need to
>   be upgraded.

- Ran `Get-SPContentDatabase -Identity DB_Content |select Name, NeedsUpgrade` and NeedsUpgrade returned False
- In Central Administration, under Manage Databases Upgrade Status, Status is No action required.
- I checked the logs and Event Id 2138 with the same description as the Health Analyzer explanation is showing up.

Why is the Health Analyzer rule reporting it as needing an upgrade and when I try the upgrade it says it doesn't need it? How can I resolve this?

Comment: is it a content database or configuration or service database? what's the last time Health anaylzer rule ran

Comment: What patch level are you at? I suggest upgrading to Jan 2019 as various previous patches, including RTM, have had this benign issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION (thanks to Waqas Sarwar MVP):Issue resolved after detaching and attaching this db from the WebApp. In my case I did it with Powershell in the App Server and running Management Shell as admin while logged as the farm account but for some reason it didn't work properly as it was being reported with Powershell as existing but it was not showing up in Central Administration. I had to detach it with Powershell and then using Central Administration add a content database. This way it worked and warning event 2138 was not showing up anymore, neither the Health Analyzer reporting it as a Warning.

Answer (score 0):

We are seeing the same issue in our environment quite often. it is kind of false positive alarm. couple of things you can do in this case:

- Make sure, you farm account and App pool account have proper permission on this database.
- Try to re-analyze the rule and many times it auto fix.
- If their is any recent upgrade in the farm then run the psconfig wizard.

After consulting with MSFT, they told us apply the latest CU. But still we are seeing this error in a while, surprising couple of times it auto fix.

In case it is bothering you then you can run PSConfig wizard which will clear all these warning.

Comment: This is the only content database that is having this issue and this started after upgrading the database layer from SQL Server 2016 to SQL Server 2017.

Comment: You can try to detach the database from SharePoint and re attach it. but plan it as it will take the sites down during detach operation. i am seeing this error at least couple of years and no satisfactory answer from MSFT,

Comment: Pool account has SP_DataAccess and Farm account has SPDataAccess and db_owner. I thought that running psconfig in this case was not required as Upgrade-SPContentDatabase is specific for 1 database, which is my case and then I don't touch the other dbs that don't have any issues

Comment: i agree with you thats why i am saying if you have a off window then try to detach and re attach it